# django - query a class by the latest created object of another class

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How to query so as to get the `thread` in the `order` that has the *latest message*.

**Edit:**

Eg:

1. Suppose, A sent a message to B, (Thread_1). Here Thread_1 is at the top.
2. Now, C sent a message to B, (Thread_2). Here Thread_2 is at the top and Thread_1 is below it.
3. Again, A sent a message to B, (Thread_1). Here again, Thread_1 is at the top and Thread_2 is below it.

models.py:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Thread.objects.annotate(max_sent_date=Max('message_set__sent_date')).order_by('-max_sent_date')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But its giving me a `nameError: 'Max' is not defined.`

Comment: Thank you so very much!!! I never knew `annotate`. Its really great to learn something new!

Comment: Just one more question though. I just found another question with its answer. Why aren't they same? `Thread.objects.annotate(Max('message_set__sent_date'))`